# What are derived files in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have problem with derived files. Some of my files in my project are 'derived'.
When I want to edit these files, I get the following message:

> "This file is derived"
>
> "Do you really want to edit?"

When I right click on this file and choose properties, I see that "Archived" is marked.

I think this is a problem with Maven, but I don't know how to fix this or know why part of my files are 'derived'.

Comment: Could you post relevant maven pom snippet and the file names/types which show up dervied in Eclipse?  Also, why would you want to manually edit derived files - the edits would be lost when the project is rebuilt.

Answer (score 31):

There isn't necessarily a problem. Derived files are those that are being generated on the basis of other files. And when you edit them, the next time they are generated, your edit is lost.

Try to find which are the source files.

Comment: Thank you Eclipse for not sitting idly by and letting me shoot myself in the foot :-)

Comment: How to find the source file?!

Answer (score 22):

I just had this problem, I accidentally dragged and dropped a package into the gen folder.  This set a flag on the package as derived.  When I copied back it still existed, and affected all the sub files.

I just right click on package, properties and unticked Derived, and problem solved.

Answer (score 16):

You probably tried to edit file in "target" directory.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and instead of editing files within the actual webapp directory, i was editing them in the target directory. If you edit things in the target directory, Eclipse literally hangs for like 5minutes so if anyone is else is experiencing the same problem, you should check whether you are editing the correct file in the correct directory.

Answer (score 7):

i had this problem after creating a LaTeX document with TeXlipse. TeXlipse placed the output (PDF) file in the same folder, and marked the entire folder with *Derived* attribute. Derived files are those that have been automatically generated and should not be edited or the changes will be lost next time the files are regenerated. Clearly not all the files in the folder were derived. By right clicking on the folder and selecting *Properties*, I could see that the *Derived* attribute was set, but unchecking it did not help (next time it was checked again).

If the problem actually is with Maven, then this won't work, but in case somebody is having this problem after creating a TeXlipse document, here's the solution:

1. Right click on the project, select *Properties*, then select *Latex Project Properties*.
2. Either uncheck *Set LaTeX output files as derived*, or modify the *Output File* path so that the file will be written into the project root or into a different folder.
3. Right click on the folder that has the *Derived* attribute, select *Properties*, uncheck *Derived*.

Comment: There's TeX support in eclipse???  Collateral damage in a good sense.

Answer (score 2):

Derived files are those are in `target` directory and has been generated for packaging. Take a look and try to edit the good ones

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem during editing Latex documents in TexLipse plugin. Accidentally, I was not able to modify my documents although before this 5 minutes ago I had had this possibility. To overcome the problem I simply deleted the project from the workspace and imported it once again. The checkbox of derived files was not checked.

Comment: I had the same problem not sure if it was caused by me renaming a package but the warning kept showing and the derived checkbox was not checked - deleted project from workspace and re-imported and now it's ok