# Eclipse - What is the derived files warning

Tags: java, eclipse

I have problem in Eclipse IDE. I accidentally clicked something while editing my JSP files. When I want to edit these files now, I get the following message:

```
"This file is derived"
"Do you really want to edit?"
```

When I right click on this file and choose properties, I see that "Derived" is NOT marked. Also, none of the solutions from SO worked - 
[What are derived files in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849173/eclipse-derived-files)

Please help.

Comment: I suspect you are opening files in a gen/build/target folder? Something which gets overwritten when you rebuild.

Comment: @jamesB - there is no target folder anywhere in my dynamic web app.

Comment: How do you build the app?

Comment: @JamesB - I just do project > build project. I had pressed something accidentally and quickly and I don't remember what it was. This problem
happened just after this accident.

Comment: Is that file generated automatically from some framework you're using or something?

Comment: @Hugo Sousa - I am not using any framework like spring, struts etc.

Comment: Can people please stop downvoting useful questions into oblivion? This question was exactly the question I had and the comments / answers here helped.

Answer (score 1):

Get into the **package** properties and untick Derived.

Comment: Unchecking derived does not work. I already mentioned this in my question. Please REMOVE your answer otherwise it will be downvoted.

Comment: You say you unchecked that in the file. I'm telling you that you can also uncheck it in the **package**

Comment: The jsp file which is causing this error is not derived. Its folder is also not derived. What do I do ?